# Symfony 2 : Doctrine OneToMany relation

Tags: indexing, symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-one

I've 2 entities :

```
class Client
{
    /**
     * @var integer $mainId
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="main_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $mainId;

    /**
     * @var string $id
     * 
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="string", length=10, nullable=false, unique=true)
     */
    private $id;

    ...
}

class Child
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var Client
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="client_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $clientId;

    ....
}
```

For some reason the foreign key from the child table doesn't point to the primary key of the Client table, but anyway I don't think that it should be a problem.

When I try to do the following action in my controller :

$child->set...
$child->setClientId($client);
$em->persist($child);

I get the following error :

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\wamp\www\myApp\vendor\doctrine\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\BasicEntityPersister.php line 510
```

I tried to add @Index anntotation in my Client Table but I still get the error...

I've never had that problem before, any help would be welcome.

**EDIT**

If I move the "@ORM\Id" annotation from $mainId to $id in my Client class, that works. Would that mean that Doctrine 2 doesn't allow foreign keys that points on 'non primary key' fields ?

Comment: what is the difference between 'main_id' and 'id' in your Client class? And why don't you do `referencedColumnName="main_id"`?

Comment: Yeah, I know it's weird, but the table was made like this and I can't alter it now (actually id is a string and mainId an auto-increment integer)... See my edit and tell me what you think.

Comment: of course you can't create a relation without a primary key...

Comment: That was not so obvious since mysql allowed it, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you simply design everything on your Database, including foreign keys, and so on...and simply create your Entities based on the database using this here?

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html

worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

`referencedColumnName` should be set to the column that has `@ORM\Id` set, so in your case `referencedColumnName="main_id"` should work

(don't forget to clear cache and run `doctrine:schema:update --force` after you change these settings)